# Uploading images for inline content without an html editor

Tags: drupal-7

I've got a client with a D7 site in which all content is created by a single employee who knows html and css, but never accesses the back end. Is there a way to let them upload images to embed in content (not a field) without installing an html editor? No styles are used or needed. The images are created just as they need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at the IMCE module?

IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.
https://drupal.org/project/imce

Comment: Thanks - I had used IMCE, but only in conjunction with html editors. Did not realize that it provided it's own link in the absence of an editor.